# inline disable button not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, button

I have two buttons, which are initially disabled

```
<button class="back" id="back" disabled="true">Back</button>
<button class="forward" id="next" disabled="true">Next</button>
```

Safari and Chrome read it just fine

[image: disabled true]

But Firefox does not

[image: disabled not read]

I'm running FF 26.0. Removing `="true"` doesn't fix it.

Comment: Try using disabled alone without the ="true", or disabled="disabled" if you must follow XHTML.

Comment: tried both, and still nothing...

Comment: That's odd. It works for me on Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/s9mHx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but after restarting FireFox, it works again. Weird...

Comment: I had the same problem and restarting Firefox helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of firefox you are using, but the latest version (26.0) seems to have no trouble disabling the button. In either case, you do not need to specify "true" or "false". Simply put

```
<button class='back' id='back' disabled>Back</button>
<button class='forward' id='next' disabled>Next</button>
```

[W3 Disabled Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)